# How to export Normal Maps from a 3D render program

Tags: export, 3d-modeling

I am using the Ethanon Engine, wich is a 2.5D engine wich loads the Lightin data from a Normal Map. I am looking for a way to export a normal map from a 3D program(such as Blender).

For instance. If I have the following pillar, made in some 3D program, and I want to export it in the current view:

[image: A pillar rendered from a 3D program]

Now, I want to get a normal map from the current viewpoint, something like this:

[image]

How can I do this? I have only found methods on the internet describing normal maps as a way to re-detail low poly 3D meshes, but that is not what I want. Those normal maps are flattened like the texture, and not from the current vieuwpoint like this.

I hope I was able to explain this problem clear enough.

*(Note: the images in this post are from a standard sample object of the Ethanon Engine)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Blender, first you bake your normal map from your high poly mesh to your low poly mesh, just as you would normally do it if you were to add detail to an otherwise simple mesh.

again, if you were to fake details you would apply the normal map as a texture and set the influence to affect the normal values (Influence panel/Geometry:Normal).

now this is where it's different: instead, just simply set the influence to affect the diffuse color (Influence panel/Diffuse:Color), leave the normal button unchecked and your normal map will be applied as if it were a simple flat texture.

finally, you might want to delete any lamps from your scene and turn on environment lighting. then just hit render and you are ready.